# Hashtags in Binding TextBlock C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a listview in my app (C# - UWP)
and in my DataTemplate i have a TextBlock that it Binding a text.

this is my code:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" FontSize="11"/>
```

Now, how can i coloring all hashtags in the text? And clickable?
Note: all captions that binding this TextBlock is variable.
Like:

This is test #message for testing

**Or**

I like #German and #Russian language

I want change color #message, #German and #Russian and clickable feature in TextBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a rich text box. Rich text box can render HTML like tags.

so you can have text like

```
<p> I am following the <a>#Russian-Language</a> <a>#azure</a> tutorials. </P>
```

Then anchor tags can have targets and they will be clickable. OR you can call a method on this hyperlink click.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a control few months back called [`HashHandleTextBlock`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/uwp.unwantedtoolkit). The core concept of this is based on `MarkdownTextBlock` of UWP Community Toolkit.

Below is how you use controls.

```xml
<UnwantedControls:HashHandleTextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=InputText, Path=Text}" 
                                      LinkForeground="DarkGray"
                                      HashPrefix="https://twitter.com/hashtag/" 
                                      HandlePrefix="https://twitter.com/" />
```

You can also download the source from [Github](https://github.com/avknaidu/UWP.UnwantedToolkit) and modify control for your requirement.